# Custom switch slide animation React Native, how to make it smooth?

Tags: animation, react-native, react-native-ios

I need to make switch slide animation, and I almost did it, the slide animation to the right looks really good, but the slide animation to the left doesn't work smooth, any ideas how is possible to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

 changeLogin = () => {
        if (!this.state.loginEmail){
            this.slideRight()
        } else {
            this.slideLeft()
        }
        this.setState({ loginEmail: !this.state.loginEmail })
      }

  handleViewRef = ref => this.view = ref;  

    slideRight = () => this.view.animate({ 

      0: {
        translateX: 0,
      },
      0.5: {
        translateX: 100,
      },
      1: {
        translateX: 150,
      },
      2: {
        translateX: 300,
    }  
      })


      slideLeft = () => this.view.animate({ 
        0: {
          translateX: 0,
        },
        0.5: {
          translateX: -0.3,
        },
        1: {
          translateX: -0.5,
        },
        2: {
          translateX: -1,
      }  
        })  


                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={this.changeLogin}>
                        <View style={styles.buttonRowTop} >
                        <Animatable.View style={styles.buttonSwitch}
                        ref={this.handleViewRef}
                       >

                        </Animatable.View>
                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', width: 260, zIndex: 100, marginLeft: -180, marginTop: 5}}>
                            <Text style={[!loginEmail? styles.textSwitchActiveLeft: styles.textSwitchLeft ]}>Phone</Text> 
                            <Text  style={[loginEmail? styles.textSwitchInactive:styles.textSwitch]}>Email</Text> 
                        </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Here is how it looks right now:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed slideLeft function, animation looks much smoother now:

```
 slideLeft = () => this.view.animate({ 
        0: {
          translateX: 100,
        },
        0.5: {
          translateX: -0.3,
        },
        1: {
          translateX: -0.5,
        },
        2: {
          translateX: -1,
        }  
        })
```

Comment: Can you please give me your style file?

Answer (score 1):

I custom the code with functional style

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { t } from 'i18next';
import appStyles from '../../../styles/global';
import COLORS from '../../../styles/colors';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

export const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
let componentWidth = screenWidth;

const TransportMethod = props => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const updateIndex = () => {
    if (activeIndex === 0) {
      slideRight();
      setActiveIndex(1);
    } else {
      slideLeft();
      setActiveIndex(0);
    }
  };

  const handleViewRef = useRef(null);

  const slideRight = () =>
    handleViewRef.current.animate({
      0: {
        translateX: 0,
      },
      0.5: {
        translateX: 100,
      },
      1: {
        translateX: componentWidth / 2 - 5,
      },
    });

  const slideLeft = () =>
    handleViewRef.current.animate({
      0: {
        translateX: componentWidth / 2 - 5,
      },
      0.5: {
        translateX: componentWidth / 4,
      },
      1: {
        translateX: 0,
      },
    });

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={updateIndex}>
      <View
        style={styles.backgroundSwitch}
        onLayout={event => {
          componentWidth = event.nativeEvent.layout.width;
        }}
      >
        <Animatable.View
          duration={500}
          style={styles.buttonSwitch}
          ref={handleViewRef}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
          }}
        >
          <Text style={[styles.textOption]}>Walk</Text>
          <Text style={[styles.textOption]}>Car</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundSwitch: {
    backgroundColor: '#F3F7F9',
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  textOption: {
    width: '50%',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  buttonSwitch: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: '80%',
    width: '48%',
    borderRadius: 100,
    left: '2%',
    right: '2%',
  },
});

export default TransportMethod;
```